# how to return the list of integer values to a method in c#

Tags: c#

I have a method in my repository which needs to provide list of integer values but I am getting the first column values only .. how can i get the all column values in my service..

this is my method in repository:

```
public List<int> GetChartInfo(string lineNo, string shiftDateTime, string station)
{
        string query = string.Format("SELECT SUM(QTY_BUILD) AS BUILD_QTY, SUM(QTY_FAIL) AS FAIL_QTY, "+
                                     "DATEPART(HH,BUILD_HOUR) AS SHIFT_HOURS FROM {0} WITH (NOLOCK) "+
                                     "WHERE LINE_NO='{1}' AND BUILD_HOUR >='{2}' AND STATION='{3}' "+
                                     "GROUP BY DATEPART(HH,BUILD_HOUR) ORDER BY SHIFT_HOURS ",_tableName, lineNo, shiftDateTime, station);

        return MitecsRepository.Fetch<int>(query);
}
```

and i called this method in my service as follows:

```
var QtyBuildList = _qtyBuildRepository.GetChartInfo(cellName, _currentShiftDateTime, tableName);
```

QtyBuildList  is getting only build_qty data only .. how can i get the fail_qty and shift_hours data also.

Comment: you should read this [SQL Injection on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: a quick tip. Take EF an you will get rid of problems like this. ;)

Comment: SQL injection aside, this is impossible to answer without MitecsRepository.Fetch<T> routine sources.

Comment: This is a confusing question. Your methods returns a `List<int>`. How would you represent multiple columns given that interface?

Comment: @user853710 Saying _use EF_ whenever people see sql query in C# is getting at the same level as saing _use jQuery_ whenever someone sees javascript. It's getting really annoying.

Comment: I agree with you.But consider this quisten posted. Putting SQL Injection aside, or the possibility to get the results of a view back, calling a stored procedurte, or any other possible way to make your life easier. When I see making mistakes like this, I can only suggest to take EF because this looks like a rookie mistake, and he would benefit a lot from EF by not dealing with stuff like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a class and return a list of this class.  For example

```
public class BuildData
{
    public int BuildQty {get;set;}
    public int FailQty {get;set;}
    public int ShiftHours {get;set;}
}
```

And then create a list

```
List<BuildData> BuildDataList = new List<BuildData>();
```

You can then loop around your data like;

```
while (ResultSet.Read())
{

     BuildData data = new BuildData();
     data.BuildQty = Convert.ToInt64(ResultSet["BUILD_QTY"];
     data.FailQty = Convert.ToInt64(ResultSet["FAIL_QTY"];
     data.ShiftHours = Convert.ToInt64(ResultSet["SHIFT_HOURS "];
     BuildDataList.Add(data);  
}

return BuildDataList;
```

So you are returning a list of BuildData rather than a List for just one of your columns.

Answer (score 0):

according to the definition of your method you are supossed to get back only a list of integers.

```
public List<int> GetChartInfo(
```

You can create a custom Class that matches the values you need and that return a list of these objects where every object represents one row result from the query.

Another thing, you could do is to to turn the query into a list.

```
var x = MitecsRepository.Fetch<int>(query).ToList();
```

then either

```
return x;
```

and change the definition of the method to the following

```
 public object GetChartInfo(
```

so you have it boxed.

Or you can do something like this if you want only one column

```
return x.Select(p=>p.Item1)
```

There is ya lot of stuff you can do But I would still tell you to consider using EF. Makes stuff like this much easier to solve.

Comment: thank you very much ... i got the exact values by creating the custom class with the same columns